# I want a button inside the edit text in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-button

I want the `Button` inside the `editText`. I am attaching the screen shot. How can I do this? Please help me.

Something like this:

[image: img]

Comment: I don't know how i can do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Enter search key" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:text="Verify"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I am using the linear layout.There is any way to do it with linear layout.

Comment: can i do it with frame layout inside linear layout?

Comment: yes, u can try...
use this in linearlayout because RelativeLayout is only for this type of layout.

Comment: Ok thanks,I am trying by using linear layout.

Comment: if you are using the linear layout just use the horizontal orientation and it should be fine

Comment: Yes I did that ...thanx

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
    android:layout_gravity="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Mobile no" >

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Verify"/>

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Read his Question properly. I want the `Button` inside the `editText`.

Comment: Ya I did this lyk above code with some modification,Thanx